# Virbr0 in virt-manager is deleted

Tags: network-bridge, qemu, virt-manager

I installed virt-manager on ubuntu 14.0.4 and installed a VM with linux ubuntu trusty. But unfortunately i deleted Virbr0. Now the machine wont work, and ifconfig on host machine does not list virbr0 and i cannot seem to find a way to get back virbr0.

Can someone please help me with this? Anything helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-start default
service libvirtd restart
```

or 
you can add another port using

```
sudo brctl addbr virbr0
sudo brctl addif virbr0 eth0
```

**Note**: This is not persistent so if you want to permanent then create in `/etc/network/interfaces` config file (or [netplan](https://netplan.io/) since 17.10+)

Comment: Hey, Firstly thanks for replying, My server is currently down please allow me to fix it and get back to this issue. A small heads up before that, I believe i already tried the above solution but when I type in:   Virsh net-destroy.  default  it produces an error message saying no default found or something. I can copy paste the exact message in a day. Sorry for delay please bear with me, i need help on this.

Comment: when you run command `virsh net-destroy default`  then it will destroy default network . so , it may be you have deleted that one so that is not there . so , run command `virsh net-start default` that will create new default file `/var/lib/libvirt/network/default.xml`  . then restart libvirtd service and still face then reboot host machine .  also share if problem not resolved .

Comment: `error: failed to get network 'default'`
`error: Network not found: no network with matching name 'default'`

This is the error that i keep getting when I destroy or net-start. Both of them dont work.

Comment: i tried to create a bridge but i didnt want to bridge it with eth0, My network keeps going down and doesnt come up when i bridge anything with eth0 and my machine does not turn back on. So can you help me please?